# Open file (.exe) with parameter lines Java

Tags: java, parameters

I'd like to start this specific programm with parameter-lines 
How could I execute this programm with parameters in Java?
I'm a newbie, I've been searching hours for a solution.

**"C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyFile.exe" -s 3 -n 100**    (what ever these parameter lines mean now)

I'm sucessfully able to launch my application, without parameters.

code:

```
String directoryFile = "C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyFile.exe"

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(directoryFile));
```

What I want:

```
String directoryFile = "C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyFile.exe"

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(directoryFile)+"-s 3 -n 100");
```

Thanks

Comment: Just beware, .lnk will pst likely need to be opened by the shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), pass each command line parameter individually

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\path\\to\\.exe",
                                  "key1", "value1",
                                  "key2", "value2") // etc.
                              .start();
```